# How to fit route bounds using CARTO-Mobile-SDK

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, maps, carto-mobile

i calculate the route betwen two points, and i get the polygon produced by the separation of this two points, i create the polygon in this way

```
let polygon = NTPolygon(poses: vector, style: NTPolygonStyleBuilder().buildStyle())
```

so, i am creating a functionality for when the route between this 2 points is to large you can press the button and the map will zoom out and show the bounding box of the route, for that i get the bounding box from the polygon `polygon.getBounds()` and i am trying to use         `map.move(toFit: NTMapBounds!, screenBounds: NTScreenBounds!, integerZoom: Bool, durationSeconds: Float)` but i dont how to get `NTScreenBounds`

Any help whit this issue, also any other approach than using map.move is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`NTScreenBounds`, in this context, is the layout of your `NTMapView`.

Here's an example from Xamarin.iOS, you should get the gist of it:

```
public ScreenBounds FindScreenBounds()
{
    var min = new ScreenPos(Frame.X, Frame.Y);
    var max = new ScreenPos(Frame.Width, Frame.Height);

    return new ScreenBounds(min, max);
}
```